# Indices: $\left(2^\left(n+3\right) - 2^n\right)/14$

Tags: exponential-function

### The questions im working on is..

$ \left(2^\left(n+3\right) - 2^n\right)/14 
$

My thought process behind solving it was to spilt the first 2 term into two separate terms then cancelling the 2^n leaving 2^3 over 14

$ (2^n \cdot 2^3-2^n)/14
$

$ (2^3)/14 = 8/14
$

however this is incorrect, how am i supposed to correctly simplify this equation?

Sorry about messing up the formatting so much

Comment: I think you should edit your question to make it clearer. Do you mean $2^{n+3}$? And are you just simplifying an expression or solving an equation?

Comment: Yeah sorry it is meant to be like that, i just dont know the proper formatting, and its only simplifying

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Consider $3\cdot 5-3=3(5-1)\neq 5$ the same is with $2^3\cdot 2^n-2^n=2^n(2^3-1)$

Answer (score 1):

Are you having trouble simplifying this fraction? Well, you have failed to see that you can factor out $2^n$ from the expression in the numerator. What you did there is an incorrect piece of mathematics. Memorize this fact: $ab \pm a=a(b \pm 1)$. The idea here is that if each term in an expression shares a common factor, you can bring it out front. Once you've factored out the $2^n$, the rest is pretty straightforward. Here's how it typically would be done:

$$
\frac{2^{n+3}-2^n}{14}=
\frac{2^n\cdot 2^3 - 2^n}{14}=
\frac{2^n(2^3 - 1)}{14}=
\frac{2^n(8-1)}{14}=
\frac{2^n \cdot 7}{14}=
\frac{2^n}{2}=
2^n \cdot 2^{-1}=
2^{n-1}
$$

And that's as far as you can go in terms of simplification.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

$2^{n+3}= 2^n2^3= 2^n×8.$

$(2^{n+3} -2^n) = 2^n(8-1)=7×2^n.$

$14=2×7$.

$\dfrac{7×2^n}{14}= 2^n/2^1= 2^{n-1}.$